# Swift and ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, swift, swift2

I am creating an online game with ruby on rails and I would like to use the same login and database on my swift application.

For example If I would to create an account on the website I would be able to login, view, and edit my account on the swift application. It would also update for the website or rails application as well. How would I do this?

Comment: StackOverflow is for asking specific questions.  Please post specific issues that you might have in attempting to implement what you described.

Comment: This is very specific and it is a problem I am encountering, isn't that what this website is for?

Comment: At no point did you ask a question.

Comment: Sorry man, I still dont know how to do this. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I am sorry if I am being a bit general

Comment: Hey @Pie Er: I strongly recommend you to read this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: We're not here to build apps for you, you should attempt to solve it and if you run into problems, provide specifics of your problem and we will help you.

Comment: I have been researching this topic for a while, there is no articles or code in the developer library. I am asking a simple question but if it is to much of a problem I guess I will take it down.

Comment: To attack this very broad issue, I recommend that you read about connection between backends and frontends. APIs and client APIs. You Ruby would be a backend application that has access to your database, then probably through a RESTful API (multiple ways to do this), from iOS you send a request to your backend (Ruby) to get the data. Your iOS app shouldn't directly access your database as that exposes a big security hole.

Comment: Never mind can't take it down I guess u r stuck with this "undefined" question.

Comment: No worries man, sorry if we're being a bit harsh, but it just seems like you need to break it down by parts and look for tutorials.  For example look at implementing a RESTful backend tutorial for rails and then how to interact with it on the iOS side, there are plenty of tutorials for both of these.

Comment: @Peyman thanks man. I appreciate the help sorry if. Did upset you in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you look into breaking this down into parts.  For example, do you have the login working on the web portion (rails)?  If so then you can begin to try to get it to work on the iOS side.  Next I would recommend you look into POST and GET requests as a basic way of talking to a back end.  Once you have gotten simple apps to work with that then you might have a better idea of the path that lies ahead.